# she sells seashells type of rhyming style

Tags: rhymes

You know how the pairing of words she sells & the word seashells sound similar in rhyme , is there a specific type of technique that has more than one word rhyme with one word?

Comment: In German, this would be called a [Schüttelreim](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sch%C3%BCttelreim) (literally, a shake-rhyme). And *Schüttelreime* are a kind of poem (not serious ones, maybe analogous to limericks in English).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure what the "specific type of technique" is that you're asking about. The specific name for the technique of matching vowel sounds (or consonant sounds) without a typical rhyme is **assonance:**

> Resemblance of sound between syllables of nearby words, arising particularly from the rhyming of two or more stressed vowels, but not consonants (e.g. sonnet, porridge), but also from the use of identical consonants with different vowels (e.g. killed, cold, culled).
>
> — [Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/assonance)

Comment: Note that if you're asking about the *technique itself* and how to do it, I'd class that as writing advice.

Comment: Isn't *she sells sea-shells* more **sibilance**, or even **consonance**?

Comment: I think the OP is asking for a term to describe the complex rhyming of multiple syllables in one part of the rhyme with their corresponding syllables in another part. +1 for *assonance*.

Comment: @Lordology "Sibilance" and "consonance" are subsets of assonance. *Consonance* is usually used metaphorically, of course.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

It's a **tongue-twister**.

> A tongue-twister is a phrase that is designed to be difficult to articulate properly, and can be used as a type of spoken (or sung) word game. Some tongue-twisters produce results that are humorous (or humorously vulgar) when they are mispronounced, while others simply rely on the confusion and mistakes of the speaker for their amusement value.

The *she sells sea-shells* one uses the technique of volatile changes between the [s] (ss) and [ʃ] (shh) sounds, which result in very difficult pronunciation.

Another example of a [s] tongue-twister is

> *The seething sea ceaseth and thus the seething sea sufficeth us.*

---

The techniques used in tongue-twisters include **sibilance**, where s-sounds are repeated ─ present in *she **s**ells **s**ea-shells*.

[Information on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sibilant)

---

*[Source: Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tongue-twister#Types_of_tongue-twisters)*.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could call that a **double rhyme**:

> A rhyme involving two syllables in each rhyming line.
>    <sub>[Source: Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/double_rhyme)</sub>

So,

- *she* **sells** / *sea* **shells**

In rap, double-rhyming is when you rhyme two words at the end of each line. Here's a well-known example:

- I started way *back* in the **day**/ now I'm a *jack* of the **trade**